# C++ array assistance

Tags: c++, xcode

I am getting an error in the word sum where it says average = sum / ARRAY_SIZE;. It is saying that the sum is undeclared. Even though I use sum previously in the getSum function, I only get the error here. I tried declaring it as a variable at the top but I am still getting that error. I do not know how else to declare it in a way that would stop this error.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

// Function prototypes
int getHighest(int numbers[],int ARRAY_SIZE);
int getLowest(int numbers[],int ARRAY_SIZE);
int getSum(int numbers[],int ARRAY_SIZE);
int getAverage(int numbers[],int ARRAY_SIZE);


int main () {

// Variables
const int ARRAY_SIZE = 12; // Array size
int numbers [ARRAY_SIZE]; // Array with 12 integers
int count = 0; // loop counter variable
string filename;


        //  Open file
    cout << "Enter input filename:";
    cin >> filename;
    ifstream inputFile(filename);   // input file stream object

    // Read numbers from file into array
    while(count <ARRAY_SIZE && inputFile >> numbers[count])
        count ++;

    // Print results
    cout<<ARRAY_SIZE<<" numbers read from input file."<<endl;
    cout<<"The highest value is: "<<getHighest(numbers,ARRAY_SIZE)<<endl;
    cout<<"The lowest value is: "<<getLowest(numbers,ARRAY_SIZE)<<endl;
    cout<<"The sum of the numbers is: "<<getSum(numbers,ARRAY_SIZE)<<endl;
    cout<<"The average of the numbers is: "<<getAverage(numbers,ARRAY_SIZE)<<endl;
       }

int getHighest( const int numbers[], int ARRAY_SIZE)
{
    int highest;
    highest = numbers[0];

    for(int count = 1 ; count < ARRAY_SIZE; count++)
    {
    if (numbers[count] > highest)
        highest = numbers[count];
    }
    return highest;

}

int getLowest(const int numbers[], int ARRAY_SIZE)
    {
        int lowest;
        lowest = numbers[0];

        for (int count = 1; count < ARRAY_SIZE; count++)
        {
        if (numbers[count] < lowest)
            lowest = numbers[count];
        }
        return lowest;
    }

int getSum(const int numbers[], int ARRAY_SIZE)
 {
    int sum = 0;
    for(int count = 0; count < ARRAY_SIZE; count++)
    sum+= numbers[count];

    return sum;
 }

int getAverage(const int numbers[], int ARRAY_SIZE)
{
    int average = 0;
    for (int count = 0; count < ARRAY_SIZE; count++)
    average = sum / ARRAY_SIZE;

    return average;
}
```

Comment: `sum` is not declared in that function.  What sum should be used? You could pass it as function argument `int getAverage(const int sum, int ARRAY_SIZE)`. You don't need the loop in `getAverage`

Comment: `sum` is **local** in `getSum`, it is not available for `getAverage`

Comment: Just because you declared `sum` in one function doesn't automatically mean it's declared in every function in your program, and it's the same object or variable. C++ does not work this way.

Comment: You can't use a variable, declared in one function, in another function. But you don't need to: the entire body of `getAverage` can be one line: `return getSum(numbers, ARRAY_SIZE) / ARRAY_SIZE;`. But be careful with integer arithmetic, here!

Comment: In C++ please use Standard Library containers like `std::vector` and stay far, far away from C-style array/length pairs. This will make your code far easier to read and debug. You can also use things like [`std::min`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min) and avoid the fuss of writing your own.

Comment: Even if `sum` was accessible, what do you expect `for (int count = 0; count < ARRAY_SIZE; count++)  average = sum / ARRAY_SIZE;` to do? It calculates the same average `ARRAY_SIZE` times..

Answer (score 1):

> It is saying that the sum is undeclared. Even though I use sum previously in the getSum function, I only get the error here.

*sum* is only a **local** variable in *getSum* so it cannot be accessed from *getAverage*, and in fact that variable does not exist anymore when you leave *getSum*

Note also the `for` in *getAverage* is useless because you do all the time `average = sum / ARRAY_SIZE;` whose value is always the same, so you want :

```
int getAverage(const int numbers[], int ARRAY_SIZE)
{
    return getSum(numbers, ARRAY_SIZE) / ARRAY_SIZE;
}
```

Note your declarations and definitions do not correspond because in your definitions the array is `const` but not in your declarations. Put the array also `const` in the declarations :

```
int getHighest(const int numbers[],int ARRAY_SIZE);
int getLowest(const int numbers[],int ARRAYSIZE);
int getSum(const int numbers[],int SIZE);
int getAverage(const int numbers[],int SIZE);
```

may be also rename `ARRAY_SIZE` to `size` to not confuse with the global variable of the same name (even they receive its value), and `SIZE` to `size` because uppercase are generally not used to name a local variable/parameter.

Out of that, you are in C++, are you sure you want to use (C) arrays rather than for instance `std::vector` allowing to not give the size in argument to each functions and also to have iterators and predefined operations etc ?

Comment: I fixed it but now I am getting 4 errors all undefined symbols, getSum(int*, int), getAverage(int*, int),  getLowest(int*, int) and getHighest(int*, int) @bruno

Comment: @newprogrammer101 you need to modify the function prototypes which you have written after "using namespace std'